# Execution flow in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, functional-programming, request, internal, control-flow

I am trying to learn MVC in detail, and I am wondering what's the exact functional flow internally, in the sense of **which functions (important functions) are called** and **what they do** when the application starts and what functions are called apart from the controller actions that we write in our application as we proceed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are the detailed steps:

1. Request comes into ASP.NET
2. ASP.NET Routing finds the route match by calling [RouteCollection.GetRouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getroutedata.aspx)
3. This in turn calls [RouteBase.GetRouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase.getroutedata.aspx) on each route until it finds a match
4. The IRouteHandler for the matching route has its [GetHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.gethttphandler.aspx) method called
5. The MvcHandler runs ([ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler.processrequest.aspx) is called)
6. The MVC controller factory locates and creates the controller in [CreateController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.createcontroller.aspx)
7. The ControllerActionInvoker determines which action to run in [InvokeAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controlleractioninvoker.invokeaction.aspx)
8. The [AuthorizationFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx) stage executes (this includes the authorization method on the controller itself)
9. The [ActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter.aspx) stage executes
10. The requested action method is executed
11. The ActionExecuted stage executes
12. If there is a result object then the [ResultExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iresultfilter.onresultexecuting.aspx) stage executes
13. If the result wasn't cancelled then the ActionResult's [ExecuteResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.executeresult.aspx) method is executed
14. The ResultExecuted stage executes
15. If an error occured then the [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter.aspx) stage executes

I would also like to refer you to the [MVC Snake Diagram](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/12/10/asp-net-mvc-design-philosophy.aspx) that I use in many presentations on ASP.NET MVC. Here's the full image: [image]

The blog post I linked to describes some of the concepts used in ASP.NET MVC regarding how data flows through the application.

Comment: I know this snake diagram, sadly this doesn't give me much info on what functions are called. Thanks

Comment: This seems better: http://www.codethinked.com/post/2008/09/27/ASPNET-MVC-Request-Flow.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Check out Redgates's free "[The ASP.NET MVC Request Handling Pipeline](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/be_ahead_of_the_game_poster1.htm?utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=textad&utm_term=2230&utm_content=nlv-aheadgame-poster-vrc&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler)" poster for execution flow

and [Steven Sanderson's MCV book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079) for details.

Comment: @Gökhan Ercan: Thanks for the poster link :)