# Differences in execution flow in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was looking around for good execution flow summaries for MVC and found this post with some good answers and links: [Execution flow in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982517/execution-flow-in-mvc)

Then I was curious, are these still current (version 3), if not, can someone post an updated overview of the flow?

If you know about changes in version 4, please share as well.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram is still valid. But here's a [more recent one](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1358). There is just only one error on step 5.: authorization filters are executed **before** model binding.

Comment: That seems like quite an error, this is a nice chart I wonder if we can get the editable file from him.